# I don't want to be prompted to boot to an OS that isn't there

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I have a computer with Windows XP on it, and for a few weeks, I added another hard drive with Windows 7 on it. I've since removed the drive that had 7 on it, but whenever I boot the PC, I'm prompted to boot to Windows 7 or to "an earlier version of windows". The really lame part is that 7 is the default option that gets chosen in 30 seconds if there's no input, meaning I have to babysit the boot for the first minute or so.

How can I remove this prompt, since there's only one OS on the system? I just want it to boot to XP, since that's the only OS available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Windows 7, it installed a newer bootloader which your system is now using to boot.  Since you are no longer have Windows 7 around to modify the bootloader you can either try installing [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) which you can use to modify the Windows Vista/7 bootloader entries.

Alternatively, you could use an XP setup or recovery CD to boot into recovery mode and reinstall the XP bootloader using the [`fixmbr`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) and [`fixboot`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) commands at the recovery console.

Comment: I'd always have a look with EasyBD instead of going straight into the boot.ini

Answer (score 1):

[How to edit the Boot.ini file in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022)

Comment: It actually sounds like he installed Windows 7 and the Windows Vista/7 bootloader has been installed, so the boot.ini file probably isn't going to do any good.

Comment: Sounds to me like he installed a HDD that already had Windows 7 on it.  Does merely having a second HDD with 7 installed modify the existing boot.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Start -> Run... -> msconfig

Switch to the Boot tab and you can delete the line that boots to XP.

[image: msconfig boot editor]